# Data breakpoint not hit: "Ignored Data Breakpoint"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm setting a data breakpoint in my application and it sometimes gets hit, but sometimes I get this message in the output:

> Ignored Data Breakpoint: Program wrote to @0xSomeAddress.

Any idea what this means? How can I prevent this from happening and have the breakpoint always break execution?

Comment: this happens for me if I set up the break point during launch of application, or sometimes when application is already running. does this also happen if you set your break points before F5 ?

Comment: @lifeOfPI I tried various scenarios (setting it before start (F5), during runtime, re-starting with it set).

Comment: Did you change your working directory? Maybe it is because VS cannot find your `*.pdb` files?

Comment: maybe [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/22d4c3d3-bf77-40ed-8b1b-64223019f3f1/vs2010-breakpoints-do-not-work-when-debugging-dll?forum=vsdebug) can help you

Comment: @lifeOfPI during the same run of the program, it sometimes gets hit, sometimes not. pdb's are fine :)